# How do I get the 'title' of the 'section' that I have the 'response' of?

Tags: google-forms

I'm trying send some conditional info from a Google Form to a Sheet on form submission

I have got the code to loop through the responses and locate which responses meet the condition (which is a string in this case), but I can't seem to find how to return the title of the section that the current response belongs to.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
function onFormSubmit(event) {


  var faultString = "EXAMPLE FAULT STRING"
  var form = FormApp.openById('1KMNq4gl3Uu2Iv7jZSM8Za9n2YejxQynxYYouThHYyi4');
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var formCount = formResponses.length;

  var formResponse = formResponses[formCount - 1];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
    var faultCheck = itemResponse.getResponse();


    if (faultCheck.includes(faultString)) {


      Logger.log('Fault found - Response to the check: "%s" was "%s"',
        itemResponse.getItem().getHelpText(),
        itemResponse.getResponse());

      Logger.log ('The section is "%s"',
        itemResponse.getItem().????());    <<<<<<<<<<< SECTION TITLE HERE
        

    }


  }

}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.    At the top of each section, there is a title and description, which I would like to access through Apps Script